# How to use the group by and max function in unix shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Input:

```
20210602_1234_abc.txt
20210603_1234_def.txt
20210507_5678_abc.txt
20210607_5678_def.txt
```

Output:

```
20210603_1234_def.txt
20210607_5678_def.txt
```

My script should first search based on the 2nd column, (here 1234 and 5678), and then select the file which has max date associated with it, (in this case), 20210603 and 20210607.

How to get this through UNIX shell script?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problem. That way contributors can understand what tools you have available/are familiar with, and you can avoid receiving proposed solutions that you already know won't work.

Answer (score 4):

With the `zsh` shell, assuming those files are in the current directory:

```
$ ls
20210507_5678_abc.txt  20210602_1234_abc.txt  20210603_1234_def.txt  20210607_5678_def.txt
$ typeset -A h; for f (*_*_*.txt) h[${${(s[_])f}[2]}]=$f; print -rC1 - $h
20210603_1234_def.txt
20210607_5678_def.txt
```

Where

- the expansion of `*_*_*.txt` will be sorted lexically, so also in chronological order.
- `${(s[_])f}` splits `$f` on `_`
- `${...[2]}` takes the second field resulting of that splitting
- `h[that]=$f`: in that loop the element of that `h` `A`ssociative array for `that` key is assigned the full filename. Because of the sorting, in the end, you'll get the one with latest date for a given `that`
- `print -rC1 -- $h`: `print`s the values of the hash `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.

If writing a script,  you'll likely want to break it down a  bit to increase legibility:

```
typeset -A max

for file in *_*_*.txt(N); do
  parts=( ${(s[_]file} )
  max[$parts[2]]=$file
done

print -rC1 -- $max
```

(here also adding the `N` (nullglob) glob qualifier to avoid the error if that glob doesn't match any file).

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and assuming the input is from a text file (this is never specified in any way by the question):

```
$ awk -F '_' 'max[$2] < $1 { max[$2] = $1; maxline[$2] = $0 } END { for (i in maxline) print maxline[i] }' file
20210607_5678_def.txt
20210603_1234_def.txt
```

This treats each input line as a set of `_`-delimited fields.  The `max` array keeps track of the maximum value from the 1st field given the key form the 2nd field, and `maxline[i]` is the full line corresponding to the maximum value in `max[i]`.

When a new maximum value for some key is found, the `max` and `maxline` values for that key are updated.  At the end, all strings from `maxline` are printed.

---

Using `sort`:

```
$ sort -t _ -k 1,1nr file | sort -s -u -t _ -k 2,2
20210603_1234_def.txt
20210607_5678_def.txt
```

The first `sort` orders the whole file by the first `_`-delimited field in reverse numeric order.  The second `sort` sorts on the second field and only keeps the first line for any value of that field.  The `-u` option to `sort` makes the utility discard lines with sort keys that have already been seen, and `-s` makes sure that a *stable* sorting algorithm is being used (i.e. one that guarantees that the lines with identical keys are not re-ordered).